# Another phrase for "glitz and glamor"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

> The world of acting isn't all glitz and glamor.

I am looking for a phrase with a similar structure, namely an [irreversible binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_binomial), to replace "glitz and glamor". The phrase doesn't have to be alliterative, but should be an idiomatic binomial pair like "glitz and glamor".

Edit:

On the research side, I did think of "flash" but wasn't able to come up with anything Googling "flash and", "phrase flash and", etc. There are a lot of synonyms for "glamor" that I thought of, but nothing as neat as "glitz and glamor" sprang to mind. The suggestions so far given in the comments and answer(s) are great!

Comment: How about _romp and pomp?_ I'm not sure if this is idiomatic, though.

Comment: Is anything wrong with “glitz and glamour”?

Comment: Razzle Dazzle? Flash and Fancy? Surf N Turf? Hollywood and Bollywood?

Comment: @user66974 No, except that I've used it in a preceding line. Don't want to recycle it.

Comment: What synonyms for the individual terms have you discovered?

Comment: Help yourself to any of [the _`GL-`_ words.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gl.pdf) Most of them have meanings coherent with _glitz_ and _glamor_.

Comment: I've edited your post to replace a term that your reference explicitly notes had been withdrawn by the original user of that term in this context, *'as "Siamese twins" had become offensive to some'* (Wikipedia, quoting Fowler's Modern English Usage 2015 edition).

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Duly noted! Thanks! Consider that phrase jettisoned from my vocab.

Answer (score 6):

There is the ***razzle-dazzle***.

If you don't mind adjectives, you could say:

> The world of acting isn't all ***loud/bright and flashy***.

(I found these on [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A%20and%20flashy&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blean%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcheap%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbright%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bflush%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfast%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bribaldry%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blight%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bloud%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhasty%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnew%20and%20flashy%3B%2Cc0))

Edit: You might also consider:

> The world of acting isn't all ***glitter and shine***.

but I personally prefer the adjective twins.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe too on the nose, but I'll add **fashion and fame.**

It carries the alliteration, goes hand in hand with "glamour and glitter"/"glitz and glamour," and there's some 80's music to back it up.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fashion%20and%20fame&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfashion%20and%20fame%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfashion%20and%20fame%3B%2Cc1)

> The world of acting isn't all **fashion and fame**.

Similarly, **fame and fortune** comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider pomp and circumstance.

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/pomp-and-circumstance.html